# Android application stats on Android market place net users/installed

Tags: android

We have recently released an application on Android Market place 
in stats it is showing

330 total installs (users)
90 net installs (devices)

we are confused as to how can there be so much difference between total installs and net installs

My question is what exactly is net installs and total installs what is the differnce?? is net install same as active install?

how can there be so much difference between net and total installs

Comment: what is the package name of your app?

Comment: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.transpacific.bm

Comment: sorry for wrong url the correct URL is https://market.android.com/details?id=com.transpacific.bmi

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> what exactly is net installs

The number of devices the app is currently installed on.

> and total installs

The number of Google accounts that have downloaded the application.

> is net install same as active install?

Yes.

> how can there be so much difference between net and total installs

1. One likely cause is that the Android developer portal is not the greatest at updating. Sometimes it can take it a day, two, or a week to update. A week would be kind of extreme, but it can happen. It is not necessarily something with the app, Google's APIs just sucks at updating the developer portal.
2. If it's a free app, a lot of people will download it, go "No, I don't really need this", and uninstall it. That is just normal behavior and it highly depends on what kind of app it is. Some apps are more easily used and deleted but some are more likely to be kept.
3. I'm betting this is not the case, but maybe your app has some errors or has a bad UI or is otherwise undesirable which is causing a lot of people to just not want to keep it. Hopefully not the case, but one thing to consider.

But point 1. and 2. can both explain the activity.

Comment: @Jakar-I was not expecting any answers to this question though your's was nice and clean answer. +1 especially for mentioning those 3 points:)

Comment: @jakar  thanks for your response .Installations are always going to be on device so how Android market place keeps a track of uninstalled applications?

Comment: @TPS Well, it doesn't list "Uninstalled" on the developer portal. But I don't know Google's APIs, so I don't know any of the information about how they track it. I basically just know what the stuff means and what happens based on my experience.